# Displaying Not Found Data From MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote simple code to fetch data from MySQL using PHP.

This is the code:

```
<?php
    $mangkal = $_POST['mangkal'];
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $long = $_POST['long'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mad");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM kendaraan WHERE mangkal LIKE '%$mangkal%' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    {
        echo "<p>";
        echo "$row[id_kendaraan]";
        echo "<p>";
        echo "$row[mangkal]";
    }
?>
```

1. The script is working, if the data is returned by the db call, I can see the results displayed. But, if the query result has no data, the script just displays blank. I want to show a message that says - 'Data not found'. How can I do that?
2. I have more than one record for a query but the script displays just one data. Please help me to show all records.

Comment: To show the message when no row is found you have to check the row count, and to show all the rows, use fetchall and then use a while or foreach loop.

Comment: @Soheyl sorry, i new to php and mysql. How to do that?

Comment: Check the answer below :)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry, I newbie with stacjoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run a loop to iterate through each result. Something similar to this -

```
<?php
    $mangkal = $_POST['mangkal'];
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $long = $_POST['long'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mad");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM kendaraan WHERE mangkal LIKE '%$mangkal%' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        echo "<p>";
        echo "$row[id_kendaraan]";
        echo "</p><p>";
        echo "$row[mangkal]";
        echo "</p>";
    }
?>
```

In the code above, a `while` loop is used to iterate through results one by one. Each time `$row` will be updated with new data and will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop like following:

```
 if($result->num_rows > 0)
 {
   while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
   {
     echo "<p>".$row[id_kendaraan]."</p><br><p>".$row[mangkal]."</p>";
   }
 } else {
     echo "No Record Found.";
 }
```

Comment: and how to displaying message that the data not exist or not matches with the query?